# One line of codes doesn't have a constructor that takes 3 arguments?

Tags: c#

For my new game button, the Game code has an error saying it doesn't take a constructor that takes 3 arguments. I have no idea how to fix it and I really need to. Anyone got any ideas please, I'm really far behind. If i can get this to work then i can actually move on at developing my game.

```
namespace Game1.State
{
    public class menu : States
    {
        private List<Component> _components;

        public menu(Game1 game, GraphicsDevice graphicsdevice, ContentManager content)
        {
            var buttonTexture = _content.Load<Texture2D>("Controls/Button");
            var buttonFont = _content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/font");

            var newGameButton = new Button(buttonTexture, buttonFont)
            {
                Position = new Vector2(300, 200),
                Text = "New Game",
            };

            newGameButton.Click += NewGameButton_Click;

            var loadGameButton = new Button(buttonTexture, buttonFont)
            {
                Position = new Vector2(300, 250),
                Text = "load Game"
            };

            loadGameButton.Click += LoadGameButton_Click;

            var quitGameButton = new Button(buttonTexture, buttonFont)
            {
                Position = new Vector2(300, 300),
                Text = "quit Game"
            };

            quitGameButton.Click += QuitGameButton_Click;

            _components = new List<Component>()
            {
                newGameButton,
                loadGameButton,
                quitGameButton,
            };
        }

        private void QuitGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _game.Exit();
        }

        private void LoadGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Load Game");
        }

        private void NewGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _game.ChangeState(new **Game**(_game, _graphicsDevice, _content));
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gametime, SpriteBatch spritebatch)
        {
            spritebatch.Begin();

            foreach (var Components in _components)
                Draw(gametime, spritebatch);

            spritebatch.End();
        }

        public override void PostUpdate(GameTime gametime)
        {
            // Remove sprites when they are no longer needed in game
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gametime)
        {
            foreach (var Component in _components)
                Update(gametime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide and mention the code where the error occurs.

Comment: private void NewGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _game.ChangeState(new **Game**(_game, _graphicsDevice, _content));
    }

Comment: Hi @JacobH, you may attach your `Game` class in the question. To fix it, please make sure you create `Game` constructor which takes 3 parameters. Thank you.

Comment: If it "doesn't have a constructor that takes 3 arguments" then either create one or use a different constructor

Comment: I expect **game** to be a placeholder that you insteted, but to helt you we really need to see the constructor to that specific object.
Thats the one that fails, as far as I can summize